# How to remove non-exact overlapping faces and vertices in blender?

Tags: modeling, sculpting, 3d-printing

I've been modifiying and sculpting on an existing blender model for a while, but then I noticed that the mesh had some weird overlappings, which is causing problems with boolean tools.

Take a look:

[image]

Using tools like "Merge by Distance" have no effect here because the planes dont have he same amount of vertices and are peer-connected to the "second layer".

Is there a way to remove these so that I have one layer only? I was not able to find a solution here.
And I dont want to spend hours of finding every face and deleting it, which also causes holes since they're all inter-connected here.

Your help would be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Hmm that is terrible topology, consider modeling it again.

Comment: I would as well consider modelling whatever this is again. Seems like something that requires manual work to fix and a lot of it for questionable result. Better to do it right from the start. From my experience, it often surprisingly ends up being faster as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could remesh your mesh (*Object Data > Remesh > Quad*).

Or select all in *Edit* mode and try the *Mesh > Clean Up > Delete Loose* function, which will remove all the floating edges:

[image]

Or try the *Mesh: 3D-Print Toolbox* addon, enable it, select your object, in the *N* panel click on the *3D-Print* tab, press the *Check All* button, in *Edit* mode press on *Non Manifold Edges* button, it will select the floating edges, remove them with <kbd>X</kbd> or click on the *Clean Up > Make Manifold* button:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, its promising, but somehow its not working for me...

Selected Non Manifold Edges:
https://i.gyazo.com/9df111fe065ff6cb3ccffa3a232c04ab.png

"Make Manifold":
https://i.gyazo.com/ebfb5cdd838e6141ff42b2a9d5f8c1aa.png

Deleting faces only leaves many holes in the mesh...

Do you have an other idea how I can solve this?

Comment: hard to say without the file, it may be too compliated to calculate, but maybe consider using the quad remesh tool?